# Construction of an elementary extension satisfying $Th(\mathcal{M}) \cup S$ where $S(x)$ is an arbitrary set of formulas

Tags: model-theory

Let $S(x)$ be a set of $\mathcal{L}$-formulas (containing at most the free variable $x$). Is there an elementary extension $\mathcal{N}$ of $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathcal{N} \models Th(\mathcal{M}) \wedge S(c)$, if $Th(\mathcal{M}) \cup S(x)$ is consistent?

I think that this is an obvious conclusion but I cannot find a rigorous way to construct $\mathcal{N}$ from an arbitrary model of $Th(\mathcal{M}) \cup S$, say $\mathcal{A}$. Do I need to start with a construction of an elementary map from $\mathcal{M}$ to $\mathcal{A}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that if you say that $N$ is an elementary extension of $M$ then requiring $N\models{\rm Th}(M)$ is redundant. Also, note that $N\models S$ is not well-defined. You could say $N$ realizes $S(x)$ or $N\models\exists x\,S(x)$, if this is what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you ask for some $N\succeq M$ that realizes $S(x)$, that is, that contains an element $a$ such that $N\models S(a)$.

The answer is `yes', if $S(x)$ is finitely consistent in $M$.

Let $L'$ be the language that contains $M$ as a set of constants plus a new constant $c$. Let $T'={\rm Th}(M)\cup S(c)$. This is finitely consistent (every finite subset of it holds in the expansion of $M$ that interprets $c$ in the obvious way). By compactness $T'$ has a model $N'$.

The required $N$ is the reduced of $N'$ to the original language $L$. The element of $N$ that realizes $S(x)$ is the element that in $N'$ interprets the constant $c$.

Comment: I cannot understand why $N$ is the elementary extension of $M$. Does the compactness theorem assure us that there is a model of $T'$ which has the expansion of $M$ as a substructure of it?

Comment: @DaleLee Adjoining each element of $M$ as a constant precisely gives us the existence of a subset in bijection with $M$ that satisfies all the same formulas.  This realizes $M$ as an elementary substructure.

Comment: @Slade Thank you very much. It's all clear now.